# Loop through array, assign each value to an element attribute in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array: 'imageIds':

```
imageIds = ["778", "779", "780", "781", "782"];
```

I want to find all elements of class .preview-image on the page, of which I know the number will match the length of the array.

I then want to assign the first matching element a data attribute 'data-img-id' with the value of imageIds[0], the second matching element with imageIds[1] etc.

So the end result would be converting this:

```
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
<div class="preview-image">...</div> etc
```

in to this:

```
<div class="preview-image" data-img-id="778">...</div>
<div class="preview-image" data-img-id="779">...</div>
<div class="preview-image" data-img-id="780">...</div> etc
```

Not quite sure how to form the loop that would achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the elements then loop through them using `each` which passes the index of the current element to it's callback:

```
$(".preview-image").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("data-img-id", imageIds[index]);
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var imageIds = [100, 200, 300];

$(".preview-image").each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr("data-img-id", imageIds[index]);
});
```

```css
.preview-image::after {
  content: "data-img-id is: " attr(data-img-id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the id array and assign the attribute to the same element of the class array with the same index.

```js
var imageIds = ["778", "779", "780", "781", "782"],
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('preview-image');

imageIds.forEach(function(id, i) {
    elements[i].setAttribute('data-img-id', id);
});

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="preview-image"></div>
<div class="preview-image"></div>
<div class="preview-image"></div>
<div class="preview-image"></div>
<div class="preview-image"></div>
```

Comment: A rare appropriate use case of `.forEach()`. +

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this: I'm not sure how you "know" the number will match the array length. Either way, it's easy to change this around to go from the array.length and add the data attribute..

```js
var imageIds = ["778", "779", "780", "781", "782"];

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.preview-image');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    elements[i].dataset.imgId = imageIds[i];

    console.log(elements[i].dataset);
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
<div class="preview-image">...</div>
```